# What is the easiest way to make a Bootstrap Carousel into a continuous scroll of images on smaller screens? I want it to scroll like instagram

Tags: scroll, carousel, bootstrap-5, responsive, responsiveness

It seems like I would have to remove all the Bootstrap Carousel classes from the image elements in order for them to become a column. I'm looking for a responsive solution to change from carousel to scroll. I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Doesn't it already behave that way for touch devices?

Comment: No, you have to swipe through the carousel instead of clicking.

Comment: Isn't that what you're asking for? Swiping is the same as scrolling.

Comment: As far as I know, swiping is a left-right movement and scrolling is an up-down movement.

Comment: I see. Why do you need it to be a carousel, then? Why can't you put some images in a `div`? You can wrap it in a div where `height` and `overflow-y` are set to "auto". That should do the trick.

Comment: it's a carousel because that is my design. it's a responsive website design

Comment: *Your design* isn't working. I posted an answer, though, and I think that's what you're looking for. Also, for future reference, posts typically get taken down if you haven't tried anything yet. You typically need to make attempts at something before asking StackOverflow how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the post. The problem is that it changes my design from a carousel to a "multi-carousel" and does not change the display responsively to scrolling on small screens. I'm looking for help implementing the design that I described, not coming up with a new design.

Answer (score 0):

I modified [the example provided by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_carousel.php) to add the classes `.multi-carousel`, `.multi-carousel-inner`, `.multi-carousel-item`, and `.vertical` to the appropriate elements. You should be able to do something similar to this for your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="demo" class="multi-carousel vertical">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="multi-carousel-inner">
    <div class="multi-carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="multi-carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="multi-carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button style="display:none" class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button style="display:none" class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <h3>Carousel Example</h3>
  <p>The following example shows how to create a basic carousel with indicators and controls.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```